# Some drawables cannot be found

Tags: java, android, android-drawable

After I had added some more vector drawables, I noticed that some of the previous ones are not working (about 11). With the rest of them I don't have any problems - they are shown properly. I link every drawable in Java class with method like `image.setImageResource(R.drawable.path_to_image);` and most of them are linked without any problems. I have such a problem with just a few ones. 
After running an app and trying to show these drawables I got such error:

```
Unable to find resource: 2131099763
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.example.example_app:drawable/f_user_achievements_learning1h with resource ID #0x7f060073
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/f_user_achievements_learning1h.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f060073
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:725)
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:571)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:767)
    at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:525)
    at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:840)
    at android.widget.ImageView.onMeasure(ImageView.java:982)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
    at android.widget.TableRow.measureChildBeforeLayout(TableRow.java:222)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1117)
    at android.widget.TableRow.onMeasure(TableRow.java:113)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.forceUniformWidth(LinearLayout.java:1000)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:980)
    at android.widget.TableLayout.measureVertical(TableLayout.java:473)
    at android.widget.TableLayout.onMeasure(TableLayout.java:436)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
    at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1293)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:340)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:911)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:676)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:479)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:676)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:479)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:671)
    at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:90)
    at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1319)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:736)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1081)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:687)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2271)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1358)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1607)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1246)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6301)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path string cannot be empty.
    at android.util.PathParser.nCreatePathDataFromString(Native Method)
    at android.util.PathParser.-wrap1(PathParser.java)
    at android.util.PathParser$PathData.<init>(PathParser.java:74)
    at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VFullPath.updateStateFromTypedArray(VectorDrawable.java:1556)
    at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VFullPath.inflate(VectorDrawable.java:1507)
    at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable.inflateChildElements(VectorDrawable.java:693)
    at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable.inflate(VectorDrawable.java:598)
    at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXml(DrawableInflater.java:130)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1227)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1200)
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:715)
        ... 74 more
```

This is the fragment of Java class, where I link drawable:

```
@Override
    protected void setChoiceState() {
        if(achievement.isAchieved()) {
            image.setAlpha(ITEM_CHOSEN);
            image.setImageResource(achievement.getResId());
        } else {
            image.setAlpha(ITEM_NOT_CHOSEN);
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.f_user_achievements_not_achieved);
        }
    }
```

Where `achievement.getResId()` is path to drawable. I've also tried to change it to raw path like `R.drawable.path_to_drawable` but it also didn't work. However, line with: `image.setImageResource(R.drawable.f_user_achievements_not_achieved);` is working properly.

Here are my .gradle files:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.example_app"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    }

    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    }
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/gson-2.8.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-lang-2.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.5.3.jar')
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.6.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

If you need any other files, just write a comment and I'll attach them

**EDIT**

I added two extra drawables (both Vector Assets) - one which hadn't been working and the other one with which there hadn't been any problems. First one is not working but the seconds one is working properly, so can be problem with just xml file representing vector drawable?

Here is an xml file for one of not working vector drawables:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.000002"
        android:viewportHeight="24.000002">
    <path
        android:pathData="M12,12m-11.803,0a11.803,11.803 0,1 1,23.605 0a11.803,11.803 0,1 1,-23.605 0"
        android:strokeLineCap="round"
        android:fillAlpha="1"
        android:strokeColor="#ffffff"
        android:fillColor="#1b1b1b"
        android:strokeWidth="0.40124387"
        android:strokeLineJoin="round"
        android:strokeAlpha="1"/>
    <path
        android:pathData="m8.02,15.376 l0,-1.975c0,-0.821 1.742,-1.929 1.742,-1.929l0,-0.662c0,0 -1.742,-1.031 -1.742,-1.852l0,-1.975"
        android:strokeLineCap="round"
        android:strokeColor="#ffffff"
        android:fillColor="#00000000"
        android:strokeWidth="1.03580773"
        android:strokeLineJoin="round"
        android:strokeAlpha="1"/>
    <path
        android:pathData="m12.623,15.376 l0,-1.975c0,-0.821 -1.742,-1.929 -1.742,-1.929l0,-0.662c0,0 1.742,-1.031 1.742,-1.852l0,-1.975"
        android:strokeLineCap="round"
        android:strokeColor="#ffffff"
        android:fillColor="#00000000"
        android:strokeWidth="1.03580773"
        android:strokeLineJoin="round"
        android:strokeAlpha="1"/>
    <path
        android:pathData="M7.18,5.604L13.463,5.604A0.295,0.295 117.507,0 1,13.759 5.9L13.759,6.087A0.295,0.295 0,0 1,13.463 6.382L7.18,6.382A0.295,0.295 0,0 1,6.885 6.087L6.885,5.9A0.295,0.295 117.507,0 1,7.18 5.604z"
        android:strokeLineCap="round"
        android:fillAlpha="1"
        android:strokeColor="#00000000"
        android:fillColor="#ffffff"
        android:strokeWidth="0.39954987"
        android:strokeLineJoin="round"
        android:strokeAlpha="1"/>
    <path
        android:pathData="M7.18,15.977L13.463,15.977A0.295,0.295 0,0 1,13.759 16.273L13.759,16.459A0.295,0.295 0,0 1,13.463 16.755L7.18,16.755A0.295,0.295 0,0 1,6.885 16.459L6.885,16.273A0.295,0.295 0,0 1,7.18 15.977z"
        android:strokeLineCap="round"
        android:fillAlpha="1"
        android:strokeColor="#00000000"
        android:fillColor="#ffffff"
        android:strokeWidth="0.39954987"
        android:strokeLineJoin="round"
        android:strokeAlpha="1"/>
    <path
        android:pathData="m8.853,15.506 l2.937,0 -1.43,-0.988z"
        android:strokeLineCap="round"
        android:fillAlpha="1"
        android:strokeColor="#ffb3cc"
        android:fillColor="#ffb3cc"
        android:strokeWidth="0.43446419"
        android:strokeLineJoin="round"
        android:strokeAlpha="1"/>
    <path
        android:pathData="m8.909,8.698 l2.804,0c0.314,0.066 -0.754,1.004 -1.399,1.366C9.655,9.709 8.665,8.784 8.909,8.698Z"
        android:strokeLineCap="round"
        android:fillAlpha="1"
        android:strokeColor="#ffb3cc"
        android:fillColor="#ffb3cc"
        android:strokeWidth="0.40527168"
        android:strokeLineJoin="round"
        android:strokeAlpha="1"/>
    <path
        android:pathData="m-21.276,14.911c0.008,0.022 0.418,1.042 0.911,2.265 0.49,1.223 0.9,2.24 0.905,2.256 0.019,0.049 0.873,0.049 0.892,0.003 0.006,-0.019 0.416,-1.037 0.905,-2.259 0.492,-1.223 0.903,-2.243 0.911,-2.265 0.014,-0.033 -0.046,-0.038 -0.418,-0.033l-0.432,0.008 -0.7,1.701c-0.383,0.935 -0.703,1.701 -0.711,1.701 -0.008,0 -0.328,-0.766 -0.711,-1.701l-0.7,-1.701 -0.432,-0.008c-0.372,-0.006 -0.432,0 -0.418,0.033z"
        android:fillAlpha="1"
        android:strokeColor="#00000000"
        android:fillColor="#ffffff"/>
    <path
        android:pathData=""
        android:strokeLineCap="round"
        android:fillAlpha="1"
        android:strokeColor="#00000000"
        android:fillColor="#ffb3cc"
        android:strokeWidth="0.84933162"
        android:strokeLineJoin="round"
        android:strokeAlpha="1"/>
    <path
        android:pathData="M17.063,16.438m-2.344,0a2.344,2.344 0,1 1,4.689 0a2.344,2.344 0,1 1,-4.689 0"
        android:strokeLineCap="round"
        android:fillAlpha="1"
        android:strokeColor="#ffffff"
        android:fillColor="#00000000"
        android:strokeWidth="0.43581513"
        android:strokeLineJoin="round"
        android:strokeAlpha="1"/>
    <path
        android:pathData="m16.973,16.438 l0,1.101 0.16,0 0.161,0 0.004,-0.492 0.004,-0.491 0.036,-0.078c0.072,-0.156 0.209,-0.238 0.395,-0.238 0.122,0 0.207,0.033 0.266,0.106 0.08,0.098 0.082,0.105 0.087,0.676l0.004,0.517 0.167,0 0.166,0 0,-0.525c0,-0.58 -0.006,-0.653 -0.073,-0.783 -0.181,-0.36 -0.752,-0.396 -0.997,-0.064l-0.056,0.075 0,-0.453 0,-0.453 -0.161,0 -0.161,0 0,1.101z"
        android:fillAlpha="1"
        android:strokeColor="#00000000"
        android:fillColor="#ffb3cc"/>
    <path
        android:pathData="m15.704,15.553 l0,0.155 0.21,0 0.21,0 0,0.885 0,0.885 0.167,0 0.167,0 0,-1.039 0,-1.039 -0.377,0 -0.377,0 0,0.155z"
        android:fillAlpha="1"
        android:strokeColor="#00000000"
        android:fillColor="#ffb3cc"/>
</vector>
```

Comment: Double check the image name first. Also there is an path cannot be empty error in your log. Verify that path too

Comment: @VivekMishra how can I verify this path because I have no idea what to do. I've also checked the names and they're correct

Comment: Print that path in logs and check your file exist on that path or not

Comment: Is the crash is happening in just pre-5.0 devices or on all of them?

Comment: @XavierRubioJansana on all of them. What's more when I use such a drawable in xml layout, everything works fine

Comment: That's weird then. I've seen the crash in pre-5.0 for XMLs, but you're describing the exact opposite. Event if you probably already tried, have you tried a clean build?

Comment: @XavierRubioJansana yes, I've tried clean build

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a line with an empty path data in the middle of the file. Maybe that's the culprit (doesn't look right for sure):

```
<path
    android:pathData=""
    android:strokeLineCap="round"
    android:fillAlpha="1"
    android:strokeColor="#00000000"
    android:fillColor="#ffb3cc"
    android:strokeWidth="0.84933162"
    android:strokeLineJoin="round"
    android:strokeAlpha="1"/>
```

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Even if in my case I found a problem in pre-5.0, vector drawables only, this workaround made it for me and may work for you:

```
VectorDrawableCompat imageDrawable = VectorDrawableCompat.create(context.getResources(), R.drawable.path_to_image, context.getTheme());
image.setImageDrawable(imageDrawable);
```

Notice that code is converted from Kotlin, and may contain typos and small errors.

Comment: So, crash is now in the line that creates the `VectorDrawableCompat`, isn't it?

Comment: yes, exactly. Hovewer, as I said before, if I link other working properly drawable, there is no error